# How to prove these algebtaic sets are isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a primitive vector $\mathbf{m} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. 
Then define a lattice by $\mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 0$, and suppose we found that it has a basis $\mathbf{e}_1, ..., \mathbf{e}_{n-1}$. Let $\mathbf{E}$ be the matrix with $\mathbf{e}_1, ..., \mathbf{e}_{n-1}$ as its columns.

Let $F(x_1,..., x_n)$ be a homogeneous polynomial with integer coefficients. How can I prove that the locus of $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{P}^{n-2}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $F(\mathbf{E} \mathbf{u})$ is isomorphic to the locus of
$\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $F(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 0$?

Furthermore, if they are isomorphic are there singular locus also be isomorphic?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are isomorphic. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\vec m = (1,0,0,\cdots,0)$ (applying an action from $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb C^n)$).

Then the lattice is defined by the equation $x_1=0$, and matrix $E$ is just the standard unit vector $e_2,e_3,\ldots,e_n$.

Then the locus of $u \in \mathbb P^{n-2}$ such that $F(Eu)=0$ is just the set $F(0,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)=0$ in $\mathbb P^{n-2}$ with coordinates $x_2,\ldots,x_n$.

The locus of $x \in \mathbb P^{n-1}$ such that $F(x)=x \cdot m = 0$ is then set of $\vec x$ such that $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1=0$.

These are evidently isomorphic since $x_1=0$ in both descriptions.

Comment: Does an isomorphism of algebraic sets retain isomorphism of their singular loci as well?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Yes it does.